# Time synchronization of views generated by different instances of the game engine

Tags: networking, real-time, game-engine, torque3d

I'm using open source Torque 3d game engine for the avia simulator project.
I need to generate single image from the several IG (image generator) PCs.Each IG displays has its own view camera with certain angle offset and get the info about the current position from the server via LAN.

I've already setup multi IG system.
Network connection is robust (less than <1 ms)
Frame rate is good as well - about 70 FPS on each IG.
However while moving the whole picture looks broken because some IG are updating their views faster than others.

I'm looking for the solution that will make the IG update simultaneously. Maybe some kind of precise time synchronization algorithms that make different PC connected via LAN act as one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a much simpler problem, but my approach might help you.

You've got to run clocks on all your machines with, say, a 15 millisecond tick.  Each image needs to be generated correctly for a specific tick and marked with its tick ID time.  The display machine can check its own clock, determine the specific tick number (time) for which it should display, grab the images for that specific time, and display them.

(To have the right mindset to think about this, imagine your network is really bad and think about one IG delivering 1000 images ahead of the current display tick while another is 5 ticks behind.  Write for this sort of system and the results will look really good on the one you have.)

Ideally you want your display running a bit behind the IGs so you always have a full set of images for the current tick.  I had a client-server setup and slowed the display (client) timer down if it came close to missing updates and sped it up if it was getting too far behind.  *You* have to synchronize all your IG machines, so it might be better to have the master clock on the display and have it send messages to speed up any IG machine that's getting behind.  (You may not have the variable network delays I had, but it's best to plan for them.)

The key is that each image must be made at a particular time, that the display include *only* images for the time being displayed, and that the composite images appear right when they should (every 15 milliseconds, on the millisecond).  Also, do not depend on your network or even your machines to do *anything* in a timely manner.  Use feedback to keep everything synched.

**Addition On Feedback:**

Say the last image for the frame at time T arrives 5ms after time T by the display computer's time (real time).  If you display the frame for time T at T plus 10 ms, no one will notice the lag and you'll have plenty of time to assemble the images.  Using a constant (10 ms) delay might work for you, especially if you make it big enough.  It may be the way to go if you always run with the exact same network.

But you are depending on all your IG machines being precisely synchronized for real time, taking no more than a certain amount of time to produce their image, and delivering their image to the display machine all in predictable lengths of time.

What I'd suggest is have your display machine determine the delay based on the time stamps on the images it receives.  It would want to increase the delay if it isn't getting the images it needs in time, and decrease it if all the IG's are running several images ahead of what the display needs.  (You might want to ignore the occasional really late image.  You have to decide which is more annoying:  images that are out-of-date, a display that is running noticably behind time, or a display that noticably speeds up and slows down.)

In my original answer I was suggesting some kind of feedback from the display to keep the IG machines running on time, but that may be overkill:  your computer's clocks are probably good enough for that.

Very generally, when any two processes have to coordinate over time, it's best if they talk to each other to stay in step (feedback) rather than each stick to a carefully timed schedule.

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying to prototype and check your idea. What do you mean by "use feedback to keep everything synched"? I synched clocks on my PCs over the network with NetTime utility and create time stamps every 30ms using sync world time.

Comment: @YuriDobronravin: Added something on feedback.  Don't know if you really need it, or if you want it precisely as I've described it, but the concept can be very useful.